# How to attach virtual disk on the fly? (virtual box)

Tags: linux, virtualbox, vboxmanage

I have this VM (ubuntu server 10.04 @ vbox 4.1.12) and I want to attach a virtual disk on it, but on the fly. I know that I can add more disks by powering off the machine and then attach them, but what I want to know is *if its possible* to attach it in a powered on machine.

Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad english :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible. You can edit the settings of the vm and add a new disk or an existing disk. However, your guest OS need to do a rescan to discover the disk and use it. So it is a multiple-step process.